# Menu Item Not Show In Action Bar In Sherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i create action menu from action bar sherlock sample like below

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar


    //Create the search view
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search for countries…");
    menu.add("Save")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.abs__ic_menu_share_holo_light)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon( R.drawable.abs__ic_search)
        .setActionView(searchView)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return true;
}
```

and my application theme theme is :

```
<style name="Theme.actor" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">



</style>
```

but menu show in buttom of activity page not in actionbar?
any suggestion?
thanks

Solution:
i change

```
sherlock.setContentView(R.layout.main_switch);
```

to

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_switch);
```

and its works perfect.

Comment: Did you set `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` somewhere in your manifest?

Comment: thanks for yr reply but i change sherlock.setContentView(R.layout.main_switch);
to    
setContentView(R.layout.main_switch);
and it work

Comment: It does not work for me